# Star Trek episode where old people have to die?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

I'm looking for a Star Trek episode, I think it's from Voyager, where the crew encounters an alien race where the elderly have to die. I know of one scene where Janeway (?) talks to a healthy and intelligent man who has to die because of this law.

I've been poring over all the Voyager episode summaries, but didn't find anything. Does anyone know which episode I'm talking about?

Comment: LOL - even though I know what the question is asking, I'm pretty sure you'd be hard-pressed to find a corporeal race where the elderly don't die.

Comment: @Omegacron: In a sense, [VOY: Innocence](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Innocence_(episode)) might count, as long as you define "elderly" not as "having spent a long time living" but "showing physical signs of prolonged existence". (No, it does not make sense in context and it was probably one of those ideas that sounded interesting on paper, but turned out silly the way they were presented.)

Comment: Janeway — very much the Lwaxana Troi of Voyager?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're referring to TNG "[Half a Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_a_Life_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))".

Per wikipedia;

> ""Half a Life" is the 96th episode of the science fiction television
>   series Star Trek: The Next Generation and the 22nd episode of the
>   fourth season.
>
> Lwaxana Troi falls in love with Timicin, a scientist who is
>   participating in an experiment to test his theories of stellar
>   ignition. Timicin hopes to use the technique to save his world's dying
>   star, but the experiment fails. Although Lwaxana encourages Timicin to
>   continue his research, the scientist reveals that he can't. It's time
>   for him to go home for "Resolution"- a ritual suicide invoked at the
>   age of sixty to save children from the burden of a parent's aging."

Comment: That's it! Now I remember Lwaxana as well. Thank you for your very quick and informative answer!

Comment: Can we have this in real life please? I love my elders dearly by the aging population is a nightmare. This episode is a great commentary on the issue.

Comment: Instead of getting rid of old people, let's start with the truly useless members of the population. So politicians, lawyers, door-to-door salesmen....

Comment: @JamesSheridan That's what the ['B' Ark](http://www.geoffwilkins.net/fragments/Adams.htm) was for.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: You sir, deserve every upvote that there ever was.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - I'd support this idea if I wasn't sure I'd end up on the "B" Ark...

Comment: Apparently we have something similar here on SE - just disagree with Jack B. Nimble.

Comment: @Gusdor Except that the entire point of the episode was to show what a completely atrocious and abhorrent  idea such a policy would be.

Comment: A superb episode.  David Ogden Stiers was (as always) sublime, and for once Lwaxanna was written as something other than irritating, bad comic relief.   I genuinely felt for her character in this episode.

Answer (score 8):

It is a Next Generation episode [Half a Life](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Half_a_Life_%28episode%29).  And it is not Janeway, it is Lwaxana Troi.

Answer (score 4):

I'm slightly late to the party here... But there's also a Voyager episode that matches your description: Emanations (S01E09). In this episode, Kim gets sucked into some sort of subspace portal that links a burial site (discovered by Voyager) to a sarcofagus on a planet where living people are killed and then sent through it into the 'next Emanation'.

Script here: http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/108.htm

Comment: You are mistaken. The aliens die and are sent through a subspace vacuole into our dimension. The big twist is that when they get to "the other side" they just stay dead. This boggles the mind of the aliens who thought that they were sending their loved ones to heaven/valhalla/eden. The second twist is that the aliens *are actually surviving beyond death* (as energy beings).

Comment: My bad. This quote specifically resonated to me very much with your question:
" NERIA: No, of course not. She didn't die until the cenotaph was activated. That's the purpose of the cenotaph. It terminates a person's life just before the appearance of a spectral rupture [...] "

Comment: I guess you could argue that they're on the verge of dying, rather than actually dead and that the machine kills them. The principle is very much the same.

Answer (score 1):

there is this one too, from the original series:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miri_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please include a description of how this matches the question instead of just an uninformative link.